# Constructing wpf in-code for Transform Group based on the xaml code

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am having problem in constructing the in-code program based on the given xaml code. Especially for the Transform Group part and the Trigger part.

```
<Window x:Class="newStackOverflow.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:newStackOverflow"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Window.Resources>
    <Storyboard x:Key="Storyboard1">
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames 
            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[3].(TranslateTransform.X)"
            Storyboard.TargetName="rectangle">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:10" Value="300"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Canvas x:Name="canvas" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Background="Green">
        <Rectangle x:Name="rectangle"
                   Fill="#FFF4F4F5" Stroke="Black"
                   Height="100" Width="100"
                   Canvas.Left="10" Canvas.Top="10"
                   RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
            <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                <TransformGroup>
                    <ScaleTransform ScaleX="1"/>
                    <TranslateTransform X="50" Y="20"/>
                </TransformGroup>
            </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
        </Rectangle>
    </Canvas>
    <Button Content="Button"
            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
            VerticalAlignment="Center"
            Padding="10 5" Margin="10" Grid.Row="1">
        <Button.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click">
                <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource Storyboard1}"/>
            </EventTrigger>
        </Button.Triggers>
    </Button>

</Grid>
```

Can you give any ideas in developing the in-code part?Thanks in advance!:D

Comment: Kind of hard to give you code without knowing what you want said code to do...

Comment: I want to animate a rectangle to move a certain amount of coordinate that i have set earlier.

Ex: My rectangle is at the position (x=0,y=0). I want with a click of a button to make it move at position (x=150, y=230) in interval of 100 milliseconds. So with one click, it would go to (10,25) at first 100 milliseconds,(20,35) for second 100 milliseconds and so on until the rectangle reach the final position(x=150, y=230)...

Comment: what have you tried? show some code?

Comment: U can refer to my in code below. Thank you:)

Answer (score 0):

these are my codes. When i tried the codes, it say that the s.Begin(rectangle) exception user unhandled.

```
  public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private Storyboard s;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();


        Button button = new Button();
        button.Height = 28;
        button.Width = 58;
        button.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
        button.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;
        button.Content = "Button";

        button.Name = "button";

        this.RegisterName(button.Name, button);

        Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle();
        rectangle.Width = 100;
        rectangle.Height = 100;
        rectangle.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
        rectangle.Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
        Canvas.SetLeft(rectangle, 10);
        Canvas.SetTop(rectangle,10);
        canvas1.Children.Add(rectangle);

        rectangle.Name = "rectangle";


        TranslateTransform tt = new TranslateTransform();
        ScaleTransform st = new ScaleTransform();


        TransformGroup tg = new TransformGroup();
        tg.Children.Add(tt);
        tg.Children.Add(st);

        button.RenderTransform = tg;


        Duration duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(10));
        DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames myDoubleAnim = new DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames();
        EasingDoubleKeyFrame myDoubleKey = new EasingDoubleKeyFrame();



        Storyboard s = new Storyboard();
        Storyboard.SetTargetName(myDoubleAnim, button.Name);
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(myDoubleAnim, new PropertyPath("RenderTransform.Children[3].Y"));

        myDoubleKey.KeyTime = KeyTime.FromPercent(1);
        myDoubleKey.Value = 300;
        myDoubleAnim.KeyFrames.Add(myDoubleKey);
        s.Children.Add(myDoubleAnim);

        s.Begin(rectangle);
        //button.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(buttonLoaded);


    }
```

Comment: What was the exception? Perhaps copy-paste the exact text.

Comment: System.InvalidOperationException. And the details says 'Cannot resolve all property references in the property path 'RenderTransform.Children[3].Y'.

Comment: well thats your problem, you have [3], the fourth element, but you only added 2 elements to the RenderTransform.

Comment: I already change into RenderTransform.Children[2].Y But then, another error showed, "System.InvalidOperationException: 'Cannot resolve all property references in the property path 'RenderTransform.Children[2].scaleY'." And it's highlighting  the s.Begin(rectangle); part.

Comment: the index is 0 based, 0 for the first element, 1 for the second.

Comment: Okey noted and I already change to RenderTransform.Children[1].scaleY but still it's highlighting the  s.Begin(rectangle); part :(